# Excel file always opens in Read-Only mode over WebDAV

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, webdav, microsoft-excel

I mapped a WebDAV drive in my Windows Explorer.
I can access files and browse etc.

But. When I try to open my Excel file it always opens in *Read-only* mode. How do I open a file so it opens with write permissions? I'm sure no-one else is working on the same file.

I'm using:

- Windows Server 2008
- Office Excel 2007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be related but there's a HotFix for this situation that worked for me:

[On a Windows Vista-based computer, you cannot access certain directories on a Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV) server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942392/en-us)

It solves the problem of always opening a file in Read-Only mode.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Office will open documents as read-only if:

1. Your your server is non-root. Microsoft Office submits OPTIONS and PROPFIND requests to site root (http://server/) and requires the server to respond properly. If your WebDAV server is non-root (for example http://server/dav/) Microsoft Office will open documents as read-only.
2. Your WebDAV server does not support Class 2. Microsoft Office locks documents when creating and opening files for editing. If Microsoft Office is unable to lock the document it will be opened as read-only.

Here is more troubleshooting tips about read-only Microsoft Office files opened via WebDAV:
http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only

Answer (score 1):

Did you check for Write permissions for user to the folder and file?

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/WebDAV-IIS.html

Comment: I'm using third party WebDAV hosting. I don't have to configure it myself. my WebClient service is running. And since I created the new file on WebDAV folder I guess I have write permissions.